# jQuery find IDs ending in \d+ regex (one or more numbers)

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm trying to find elements based on dynamic end of ID, which contains one or more numbers, ie:

```
<div id="banana12"></div>
<div id="apple3"></div>
```

I've tried using jQuery selectors such as:

```
find("[id$=/\d+/]")
find("[id$='/\d+/']")
```

To no avail. Is it possible to use such a syntax or a full regex pattern to find match my desired elements?

*UPDATE*

The exact code block I'm attempting to use it in:

```
$.each($('#service_block' + pad(each_panel_incrementer, 2)).find('[id~=/\d+/]'), function (index, value){
    //    
});
```

In which first answer's pattern returns "unrecognized expression".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily write one

```
$('[id]').filter(function(){
    return /\d+$/.test(this.id)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aXxD3/)

I would recommend adding a element selector along with it for performance reasons

---

Update

```
$('#service_block' + pad(each_panel_incrementer, 2)).find('[id]').filter(function () {
    return /\d+$/.test(this.id)
}).each(function (index, value) {
    //    
})
```

Comment: updated OP. Is it possible to use the pattern within the find block I have?

Comment: with updated, I'm receiving "Object 01 has no method 'find'".. I'll try putting the each() back to beginning...

Comment: @lalalalalalalambda looks like I missed a `)` after `pad(each_panel_incrementer, 2)`